# Probability Distribution Minus

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a probability distribution for products entered a warehouse for example $f(x)$.
I also have a probability distribution for products going out of the warehouse for example $g(x)$.

I want to know the probability distribution of inventory level (Inventory=Out-In)

Answer (score 0):

Let the incoming items for an inventory period be random variable $X\in [0,\infty)$ with density measure $f$.

Let the outgoing items for an inventory period be random variable $Y\in [0,\infty)$ with density measure $g$.

**Remark** We will have to assume *for the sake of modelling* that the inventory is never depleted.   In actual practice $Y$ should be restricted to no more than the current inventory level.   Further we shall assume independence of incoming and outgoing items.

We wish to find the density measure $h$ of random variable $Z = X-Y$, the *change* in inventory level.   So $Z\in (-\infty,\infty)$.  (See the remark above.)

$$\begin{align}\because
\forall z\ge 0, P(Z\le z \mid z>0) & = P(X\le z+Y)
\\ & = \int_0^\infty P(X\leq z+y)g(y)\operatorname{d}y & \ni X\bot Y
\\ &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^{z+y} f(x)g(y)\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y
\\[2ex]\therefore
\forall z\ge 0, h(z) & = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}z} \int_0^\infty \int_0^{z+y} f(x)g(y)\operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y
\\ & = \int_0^\infty f(z+y)g(y)\operatorname{d}y
\\[2ex]\text{similarly:}
\\ \forall z<0, h(z) & = \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x-z)\operatorname{d} x
\\[3ex]
h(z) & = \begin{cases}\int_0^\infty f(z+y)g(y)\operatorname{d}y & z\ge 0
\\ \int_0^\infty f(x)g(x-z)\operatorname{d} x & z\le 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$